# Grafo con caracteristicas que desee el usuario en python (Problema con add_edge_from) ¿como puedo hacerlo?

Tags: python

no tengo mucha experiencia programando entonces he decidido pedir ayuda ya que no puedo arreglar un error que me ha estado molestando hace rato, una parte del proyecto es crear un algoritmo donde se pidan valores al usuario y que con ello se cree un grafo, con aristas y nodos correspondientes a lo que el usuario dio.
Tengo esto

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lista = []
cantidad = int(input("Introduce la cantidad de valores: "))

for num in range(cantidad):
    uno = input("Especifica las conexiones: ")
    lista.append(uno)
    
lista= [element.split(',') for element in lista]
miDiccionario = dict((key,value) for key,value in lista )
print(miDiccionario)

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([miDiccionario])
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

Con este código lo que hago es pedir la cantidad de valores que va a contener la lista, con esa cantidad pasa a un `for` el cual se ejecuta la cantidad de veces que esta guardada en `cantidad`
guardando dos valores separados por `,` en la `lista`. Al terminar de ejecutar eso tomamos la lista y la convierto en un diccionario, ya que si no lo hago en la funcion `add_edges_from` no me tomara la lista. Una vez que se convierta en `miDiccionario` lo paso como parametro a la funcion `add_edges_from` y creo el grafico.

Al ejecutar este código con el valor 2 en `cantidad`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando intento introducir 3 conexiones me da este error:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al intentar introducir mas de 3 conexiones tengo otro error:

```
Edge tuple {'1': '2', '2': '3', '3': '4', '4': '1'} must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho sus respuestas, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué hace add_edges? Debes añadir ese código a tu pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo se supone que crea las aristas entre los nodos que serian los números, ya que por ejemplo tengo este código que me crea un grafo totalmente bien. `import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,2)])
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)

plt.show()`

Comment: Pero lo que necesito es que esos nodos y aristas las cree el usuario

Comment: El código va en tu pregunta (como te indiqué). Ver la indentación de código python en un comentario es... complicado

Comment: Perdón no sabia como comentarlo;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No conozco los paquetes que estás usando, pero de tus comentarios me parece que tienes que pasar una lista, no un diccionario.

Reduje el código a esto:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lista = []
cantidad = int(input("Introduce la cantidad de valores: "))

for num in range(cantidad):
    uno = input("Especifica las conexiones: ")
    lista.append(uno)

g = nx.Graph()
lista = [element.split(',') for element in lista]
g.add_edges_from(lista)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

**Demo**

```
Introduce la cantidad de valores: 4
Especifica las conexiones: 1,2
Especifica las conexiones: 2,3
Especifica las conexiones: 3,4
Especifica las conexiones: 4,1
```

produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta funciona de maravilla, también implemente un algoritmo mas fácil usando for, si les interesa la dejare en una respuesta mas abajo.

Comment: Bienvenido @user198775 ! Si la respuesta te ha parecido correcta, puedes marcar la respuesta como "respuesta correcta", esta es la forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow :) . Además así ayudas a que la respuesta perdure en el tiempo y sea útil para personas que tengan la misma duda que tú en el futuro! Si puedes echale un vistazo a: [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)